# ValueError: cannot switch from manual field specification to automatic field numbering

Tags: python, python-3.x, string-formatting

The class:

```
class Book(object):
    def __init__(self, title, author):
        self.title = title
        self.author = author

    def get_entry(self):
        return "{0} by {1} on {}".format(self.title, self.author, self.press)
```

Create an instance of my book from it:

```
In [72]: mybook = Book('HTML','Lee')
In [75]: mybook.title
Out[75]: 'HTML'
In [76]: mybook.author
Out[76]: 'Lee'
```

Please notice that I didn't initialize attribute 'self.press',while use it in the get_entry method.Go ahead to type in data.

```
mybook.press = 'Murach'
mybook.price = 'download'
```

Till now, I can specify all the data input with `vars`

```
In [77]: vars(mybook)
Out[77]: {'author': 'Lee', 'title': 'HTML',...}
```

I hardtype lot of data about mybook in the console.When try to call get_entry method, errors report.

```
mybook.get_entry()
ValueError: cannot switch from manual field specification to automatic field numbering.
```

All this going in interactive mode on console.I cherish the data inputed, further to pickle `mybook` object in file. However, it is flawed. How can rescue it in the interactive mode.
or I have to restart all over again.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

```
return "{0} by {1} on {}".format(self.title, self.author, self.press)
```

that doesn't work. If you specify positions, you have to do it through the end:

```
return "{0} by {1} on {2}".format(self.title, self.author, self.press)
```

In your case, best is to leave python treat that automatically:

```
return "{} by {} on {}".format(self.title, self.author, self.press)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
print ("{0:.1f} and the other no {0:.2f}".format(a,b))
```

> python cannot do both manual and automatic precision handling (field numbering) in a single execution of code. You can either go for specifying the field numbering for each variable or let python do it automatically for all.

Comment: where is `b` used here?

Answer (score 1):

Well if can give a proper output in a table format if
instead of using format go for f"" ;

for e.g

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title><strong>Unable to handle Value Error</strong></title>
</head>
<body>
<p><ol>for name, branch,year in college:</ol>
         <ol> print(f"{name:{10}} {branch:{20}} {year:{12}} )</ol>
    
    <ol>name       branch               year    </ol>
    <ol>ankit      cse                         2</ol>
    <ol>vijay      ece                         4</ol>
<ol>    raj        IT                          1</ol>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Escape the special characters
eg: `'{}' -> '{{}}'`